# Music Production with FL Studio

Tags: music, production

I'm currently doing bedroom DJing at the moment and uploaded some mixes to Mixcloud, but I also want to enter Music Production and I'm learning to use FL Studio, but I've barely any music background apart from bedroom DJing, where would be the best places/resources on the Internet to get me started with FL Studio (and Music Production in general)?

**Note:** I have plugins Nexus and Sylenth 1 plugins installed at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**Your best shot is FL. Studio tutorials on youtube**.
I started with Fruity Loops about 8-9 years ago, and evolved ever since only with self-motivation, a handfull of bad projects, sharing techniques with friends using the same software, "Youtube tutorials", and some more self motivation. Now i'm using Maschine, Reason, Cubase even Pro Tools with the "basic" knowledge i got from FL Studio trough the years. 
The more you do, the better you'll get! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Newgrounds has done a great job at building a community for indie composers to share their work with people of the same interest.
If you're looking to get a little extra cash for your work, I'd take a look at Audio Jungle as they too have a really good community full of indie composers, as well as professionals who make a living from the site.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other good responses here, don't forget about the vibrant communities supporting both audio engineering in general and FL studio specifically.  Many of the top/more popular posts have extremely valuable advice, and you can regularly about new good techniques just by browsing a bit each day.

https://www.reddit.com/r/audioengineering or /r/FL_Studio

http://forum.image-line.com/

Of course, if you're really extremely fresh to this, all tutorials will pale to simply making a dozen crappy music projects over the next year.  As you run into an issue, or see an opportunity to obtain better sound, do some research into how or why.  As you get more comfortable with just using the DAW to do basic things you can really dive into recording technique, and not be totally confused when somebody mentions sweeping a narrow EQ through a sample.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind! :)